# run Apache and node.js in subfolder

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js, meteor

I would like to run a meteor.js app in a subfolder (`/home/www/public/v1`) of a domain (`/home/www/public`) served by an Apache (2.4.7) server.
I have set up a virtualhost which listens to port 80, and proxies locations starting with "v1" to the nodejs app.
It works fine (I think) except that I get a 404 page generated by meteor.js.

Must I modify the meteor.js setup to accept requests coming from "domain.tld/v1" instead of "domain.tld" ? If so, which file(s)? Is this sort of setup possible at all?

**The virtualhost configuration** (edited for legibility)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /home/username/www/domain.tld/public

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/username/www/domain.tld/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

        # NODEJS APP in V1 FOLDER
        ProxyRequests on
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    <Location "/v1/">
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Configuration

You configuration is correct but some options are outdated and other not needed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /home/username/www/domain.tld/public

    <Directory />
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/username/www/domain.tld/public/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    # NODEJS APP in V1 FOLDER
    <Location "/v1">
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/V1
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/V1
    </Location>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Meteor.js will be redirected from port 3000/v1 to port 80/v1

#### More info:

This no more exist in Apache 2.4

```
Order allow,deny
allow from All
```

This is needed when you got restriction

```
Require all granted
```

This will make your server to proxy any request, and it is not required for what you need (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests)

```
ProxyRequests on
```

This is optional in your case (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost)

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. Do I have to modify the meteor.js application setup ? It sits in a "v1" folder.

Comment: i changed `/v1/` to `/v1` to prevent 404 error when you do `domain.tld/v1` without trailing slash. But to fully works, link need to be subtitute else files will miss `/v1` in their path

Comment: I didn't found how to redirect the proxy content, but this is a trick : if proxy path is the same as proxied path all will works, so put your test project in http://localhost:3000/v1 (i edited my post)